# Create Trigger that Insert data after update on specific column

Tags: triggers, sqlsrv

So i want to insert data to history_rent table and delete data in rent table after update status_peminjaman column on rent table, i am already create Trigger but it doesn't triggered

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER AfterUpdateStatus on dbo.peminjaman
FOR UPDATE
AS DECLARE
@nama_peminjam varchar(100),
@tanggal_pinjam datetime,
@tanggal_kemblali datetime,
@nama_guru varchar(100),
@status_peminjaman varchar(50),
@kode_barang varchar(255);
SELECT @nama_peminjam = ins.nama_peminjam FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @tanggal_pinjam = ins.tanggal_pinjam FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @tanggal_kembali = ins.tanggal_kembali FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @nama_guru = ins.nama_guru FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @kode_barang = ins.kode_barang FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @status_peminjaman = ins.status_peminjaman FROM INSERTED ins;
IF UPDATE(status_peminjaman)
BEGIN
    SET @status_peminjaman = 'Selesai'
END
INSERT INTO dbo.history_peminjaman
VALUES(@nama_peminjam,@tanggal_pinjam,@tanggal_kembali,@nama_guru,@kode_barang,@status_peminjaman);
PRINT 'TRIGEREDDDDDDDDD'
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger is for update only `FOR UPDATE` that is why it won't be triggerred when `INSERT`

Comment: If your trigger executes multiple statements then they must be inside BEGIN .. END block. Your INSERT statement is outside the trigger because of this.